# Changing solution configuration for AWS CloudFormation publishing in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm using the [AWS Visual Studio Toolkit](http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) to publish an application to CloudFormation.  I have several different solution configurations (debug, release, custom, etc.) that trigger app.config transformations depending on what environment I am publishing to (test, staging, production, etc.)

How can I specify which Visual Studio solution configuration should be used when publishing using the AWS Toolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simpler than it seems!  Simply change the solution configuration in Visual Studio using the dropdown in the toolbar prior to publishing.  The AWS Toolkit uses the active solution configuration when publishing.